# Como contar el número total de filas en otro input con php y javascript

Tags: php, javascript

espero se encuentren muy bien.

Tengo el siguiente código.

index.php

este código me permite seleccionar varios registros y en conjunto con el javascript poder ir agregando filas de registros para luego insertar todo a la vez.

```
<script>
// nuevo método para eliminar la fila, recibe como parámetro el botón presionado 
// y navega hasta el nodo de la fila para eliminarla

 function eliminarFilatre(boton){
 // navegar hasta el nodo fila
 fila = boton.parentNode.parentNode;
 // navegar al nodo superior de la fila y borrar la fila
 fila.parentNode.removeChild(fila);
 
 
}
    function guardar(){

        var _posatendi = document.getElementById("posatendi").value;
        var _tipotrabajo = document.getElementById("tipotrabajo").value;
        var _horainicio = document.getElementById("horainicio").value;
        
        var fila="<tr><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='posatendi[]' value='"+_posatendi+"' readonly>"+
            "</td><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='tipotrabajo[]' value='"+_tipotrabajo+"' readonly>"+
            "</td><td>" +
            "<input type='time' name='horainicio[]' value='"+_horainicio+"' readonly>"+
            "</td></tr>" +          
            
 // botón que llama al método eliminar fila y pasa como parámetro
 // el botón
"<td><button onclick='eliminarFilatre(this)'>-</button></td>" ;

        var btn = document.createElement("TR");
        btn.innerHTML=fila;
        document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
    }

</script>



<h2>TRABAJOS</h2>
                        
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>NRO</th>
                                    <th>CONCEPTO</th>
                                    <th>HORA INICIO</th>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
    <th>
    <select id="posatendi">
    <option></option>    
    <option value="1">1</option>    
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select></th>
<?php
   $sql8 = "SELECT id_trabajo,nom_trabajo FROM para_trabajos WHERE cliente='$acliente'";
   $result8=mysqli_query($conn,$sql8);
?>                                   
    <td style="font-size:12px;">
    <select id="tipotrabajo">
    <option></option>    
<?php
    
    while ($row8 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result8))
    {
    ?>  
        <option value="<?=$row8['nom_trabajo']?>"><?=$row8['nom_trabajo']?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select></td>
                                    
    <td><input type="time" id="horainicio"></td>
                                    
                                
                                </tr>                           
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
<br>
<button onclick="guardar()">Agregar fila</button>
    
                    
<hr>

<form action="insertar_trabajos.php" method="POST">
    
    <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablita">

            </tbody>
        </table>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="GUARDAR"/>

        
</form>
```

Lo que estoy buscando es que en ese mismo index poder contar la cantidad de filas en un input fuera del form, ejemplo:

Si agrego dos filas de registros que en otro input fuera del formulario me muestre el nro. 2

La idea seria que lo hiciera en tiempo real sin recargar la pagina, creo que javascript serviria de mucho para eso.

Solo que no se como hacerlo, no tengo tanto conocimiento en javascript.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar me serviría de mucho.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Estás creando filas, pero no las envías a PHP, cuando recargues la página se perderán, ¿es ese el funcionamiento esperado?

Comment: @Triby buenos días, ya el código que tengo funciona super bien con php y javascript, lo que hago es seleccionar registros y luego con el boton agregar fila me mantiene la información y va creando más filas las que quiera mejor dicho y luego guardo eso sin problemas en la base de datos, lo que busco hacer es que en un input aparte me cuente cuantas filas estoy guardando solamente que se vea en un input en pantalla.